# sencha touch scroll position

Tags: list, scroll, sencha-touch-2

I have a list which is loaded partially with the help of ListPaging plugin. When i change the view and return back to same list, only last items is loaded. I can load the next pages however i can not load the previous ones.

As a result of this, i send the data starting from 0 and finishing in last index from the server. But in this situation, scroll position is lost and it automatically scrolls to top after refresh.

How can i maintain the scroll position or is there a way to load previous records like the ListPaging plugin does for next pages?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can take a look at the loadPage(), nextPage() and previousPage() in the store documentation: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store

Comment: thank you for your advise, i apply previousPage() functionality but i wonder something, is there a way to append them to existing records? When i set "clearOnPageLoad : false", it appends the new records at the end of the list, i want them to be appeared on the top.

Comment: Hmm not that I know. I guess you would have to create you own store override.

Answer (score 1):

i think the problem you are facing is this

[list-scrollToTopOnRefresh](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.DataView-cfg-scrollToTopOnRefresh)

This is set to true at default set it to false and try again... Hope it helps

Comment: I use ListPaging plugin, and it sets scrollToTopOnRefresh false automatically.